# Store API key for requests

Tags: python

I have some classes in different .py files doing REST API calls to a service using a Bearer auth key.
Since I don't want to store the key in every class I would want to know how I should approach this.

Where and how should I store the key? How should the classes using this key access it?

Comment: A decent method is to write the key to a file set read by user only. The classes just read that well known file. Now whoever knows your password and login can get it. So can the administrator. Or anybody who steals your hard drive. So be careful about that! Your linux ssh key is secured that way. Here's mine: `-rw------- 1 td td 2602 Aug 18 15:19 id_rsa`.

Comment: As for just structuring a program in general, I assume you mean essentially building your own library and knowing where to put all the files in a repository, not just writing scripts. Here's a good model to follow: https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/#application-with-internal-packages

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Your key is a shared piece of data, I assume. So obviously you should keep it in one place and share it. You can store it in environment, or some configuration file, or maybe even pass it via command line, but ultimately it will end up somewhere in memory of your program, represented probably as a string in some some .py file. Also what do you mean by "how should classes access it"? Read a variable and pass it wherever it is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Best" is subjective, but *frequently used* on the other hand is to define your necessary keys [in environment variables](https://12factor.net/config)

For example,

config.py

```
import os
key = os.environ['MY_KEY']
```

main.py

```
from config import key
print(key)
```

Run it like

```
export MY_KEY='foobar'  # set instead of export on Windows
python main.py
```

Alternative solutions include using Hashicorp Vault, or a Key Manager
in the cloud provider of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

One good approach would be to make a Base class which loads the api key (and potentionally any other env variables) from a .env file and stores it as a class member. Then all classes which need the api key access would just inherit from Base class.

Don't forget to add .env file to .gitignore, so you don't share all the private information with other users.